# How to use flutter negation operator in stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, operator-keyword

In normal approach to use negation operator is like this

```
isValid = !isValid
```

but this approach is not working inside stateful widget constructor variable like

```
widget.isValid = !widget.isValid
```

How to make this second approach valid .

Comment: you cannot change a final variable that is declared in the Stateful widget class, instead, create one in the State class. then you can use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the negation to just `widget`, It needs to be added to `widget.isValid` . Hence wrap it within brackets to work.

Change `!widget.isValid` to `(!widget.isValid)`

#### Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  bool value = true;
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Text((!widget.value).toString())),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]